# Book on Lipschitz pointwise constant

Tags: analysis, reference-request

Does anyone know of a book (or possibly an accessible paper) discussing Lipschitz pointwise constants and perhaps including some examples?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much anything under the heading of *analysis on metric spaces* will deal with this thing, since it is a substitute for $|\nabla u|$ in metric space setting. Specifically, I recommend

- *[Nonlinear Potential Theory on Metric Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=303719099X)* by  Björn and  Björn
- *[Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0387951040)* by Heinonen
- *[Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf)* by Heinonen
- (more advanced) *[Nonsmooth Calculus](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-02/S0273-0979-07-01140-8/)* by Heinonen

The above are reasonably accessible sources, and it is advisable  to read them before proceeding to more specialized literature on "Lip-lip" properties, etc (Gong, Keith, Schioppa...)